# Creating a Meteor Package: Request CLI Inut After 'Meteor Add'

Tags: meteor

Trying to make a meteor package that would help people connect DBaaS platforms.

After adding the package, I'd like to have a prompt for CLI input. The input would effectively be the "string" of your database hostname.

Is there a way to invoke a prompt after typing 'meteor add'? Can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not tell the user (in your docs or somewhere else) to add some JSON settings or maybe environment variable?

Comment: You're right, the change is trivial... a json setting is really all it takes... but it would be slick have it simply an input method.